# Juniper VPN - Block connections when on internal LAN

Tags: networking, vpn, juniper

I would like to know if it's possible to block my users from connecting to the corporate VPN when they are on the internal company network. I have users that tend to leave it connected while at work and then complain about network speeds.

I'm using a Juniper SSL, don't have the model number at the moment but can get it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Pulse, you can restrict IP's under 'User Roles'. Pick the user role that you want to restrict, under the 'General' tab you'll see 'Restrictions'. Within that tab, you'll find 'Source IP' and here you can add the subnets you want to deny. Make sure to put the denied subnets first then add the 0.0.0.0 allow at the bottom.